# Reading a line from a txt file and catching invalid numbers

Tags: c++, file

Say I have a `.txt` file which looks like this:

```
1234,3345
1246,3837
1283,5555
12P4,5730
```

I read each line as an `int`, but when I get to an invalid number like `12P4`, how would I catch it without crashing the program and instead storing the invalid number in a list?

I am able to read it line by line, but I'm not sure how to catch the invalid number and continue processing more lines, catching more invalid numbers if present.

Comment: So it didn't process how the txt file would look like but each number separated with a comma is a new line

Comment: Simplify: store `"12P4,5730"` as a string, and use it to create an `std::stringstream` object. Try extracting two integers from the stream and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you read your file one line per loop iteration, using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). In every loop iteration, you call [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to split the line into two strings, in which the first string contains everything before the `,` and the second string contains everything after the `,`. You can then use the function [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to attempt to convert the string to an integer. If this function fails, it will throw an exception. Also, using the middle function argument of `std::stoi` you can check whether the entire string was converted.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input( "input.txt" );
    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( input, line ) )
    {
        int num1, num2;

        //find delimiter
        std::string::size_type pos = line.find( ',' );
        if ( pos == std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cerr << "Warning: Skipping line due to splitting error!\n";
            continue;
        }

        //split line into two tokens
        std::string token1 = line.substr( 0, pos );
        std::string token2 = line.substr( pos + 1, std::string::npos );

        //attempt to convert both tokens to integers
        try
        {
            size_t chars_matched_1, chars_matched_2;

            num1 = std::stoi( token1, &chars_matched_1, 10 );
            num2 = std::stoi( token2, &chars_matched_2, 10 );

            if (
                chars_matched_1 != token1.length()
                ||
                chars_matched_2 != token2.length()
            )
            {
                std::cerr << "Warning: Skipping line due to only partial conversion!\n";
                continue;
            }
        }
        catch ( const std::invalid_argument& )
        {
            std::cerr << "Warning: Skipping line due to conversion error!\n";
            continue;
        }
        catch ( const std::out_of_range& )
        {
            std::cerr << "Warning: Skipping line due to out of range error!\n";
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Found line with " << num1 << " and " << num2 << ".\n";
    }
}
```

For the input specified in the question, this program has the following output:

standard output (`std::cout`):

```
Found line with 1234 and 3345.
Found line with 1246 and 3837.
Found line with 1283 and 5555.
```

standard error (`std::cerr`):

```
Warning: Skipping line due to only partial conversion!
```

As you can see, it was detected that the string `"12P4"` could only be partially converted to an integer, so that line was skipped and a warning message was generated.

Comment: Minor nitpick - exceptions should be caught by `const` reference

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Read each line from the file into a string.
Step 2: Check the line consists of "number comma number".

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
   // Read a line.
   std::istringstream   lineStream(line);
   int a, b;
   char x = 'X';
   char rem;

   if (lineStream >> a >> x >> b && x == ',' && !(lineStream >> rem)) {
       // Checks
       // 1: You can correctly read a Number char Number.
       // 2: The character you read is a comma
       // 3: There is no more text on the line that needs reading
       //    after the second number.
   }
   else {
       // There was a failure reading the numbers and/or comma
       // This will catch the 12P
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick - consider using `std::istringstream` instead. Only input is being consumed from the stream, no output is being written to the stream, so the output capabilities of `std::stringstream` should not even be present in the stream object.